# Apache RewriteRule with option PT breaks PHP $_GET superglobal

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I have an apache rule

```
RewriteRule ^/oldURL/$ /newURL/ [PT,L,NC,QSA]
```

When I hit domain.com/oldURL/?key=value PHP does not parse the query string into the $_GET superglobal unless I remove the PT and L flags.  The REQUEST_URI has the query string on it but $_GET is empty.  I could manually parse the query string but that would require changing core code, which is locked.

Comment: Is this rule in .htaccess or in Apache config? If you have other rules then show all of them in question.

Comment: apache config.  This is the only rule that affects this url

Comment: Then why do you need `PT` here?

Comment: We have a system that forwards all 404s to another firm that hosts some of the more secure parts of site.  We are restructuring our site and we need to change some of these urls.  To do so we need to rewrite the backend curl request.  PT populates the $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"] super global.  Which we then use to forward the request.

Comment: So By removing PT this super global is not populated?

Comment: Correct! The only solution I have found so far is to set a server variable like so `RewriteRule ^/oldURL/$ - [L,NC,VAR:\/newURL\/]`. but that is disgusting and unmaintainable